# Circular drop shadow example

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sorry for such an elementary question, but all the examples I could find in search were too complicated.

I'm trying to recreate a circular drop shadow example from the pgf manual. What  packages are necessary and where do I place

```
shadow scale=1.1, shadow xshift=.3ex, shadow yshift=-.3ex,
fill=black, path fading={circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent},
every shadow,
```

in regards to the rest of the code?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} {1,...,8}
    \node[circle,circular drop shadow,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,thick]
      at (\i*45:1) {Circle \i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The needed library is `shadows`. The thing you want to place is the default setting. (Though, you can adjust the shadow if you use options like `circular drop shadow={<options>}`.) Note that you missed `\foreach in` while copying the example from the manual (which is to prepended to the `{1,...,8}`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the example you need the `shadows` library; I added the `\foreach` line that you missed in your code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
\node[circle,circular drop shadow,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,thick]
at (\i*45:1) {Circle \i};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The lines

```
shadow scale=1.1, shadow xshift=.3ex, shadow yshift=-.3ex,
fill=black, path fading={circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent},
every shadow,
```

are the default options for this kind of shadow, which you can change using  `circular drop shadow={<options>}`. If you want to modify the `path fading`, you will also need the `fadings` library :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
{
\node[circle,circular drop shadow,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,thick]
at (\i*45:1) {Circle \i};
\node[xshift=5cm,circle,circular drop shadow={fill=orange!50,shadow xshift=0.5ex,shadow yshift=0.5ex,path fading={circle with fuzzy edge 10 percent}},draw=blue,fill=blue!20,thick]
at (\i*45:1) {Circle \i};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]